# Breeze how to use client side property in Where clause

Tags: typescript, breeze

I've got only client side Metadatstore:

```
initialize = (metadataStore) => {
    metadataStore.addEntityType({
        shortName: "AppsListHelper",
        namespace: NFL.settings.entityNamespace,
        dataProperties: {
            Path: { dataType: "String" },
            Title: { dataType: "String", isPartOfKey: true },
            Author: { dataType: "String" },
            Description: { dataType: "String" },
            ImageUrl: { dataType: "String" },
            IsFavourite: { dataType: "Boolean" },
            AppTypeName: { dataType: "String", isPartOfKey: true },
            Departments: { dataType: "String" },
            AlwaysShownTo: { dataType: "String" },
            AvailableTo: { dataType: "String" },
            HasAccess: { dataType: "Boolean" },
            Keywords: { dataType: "String" }
        }
    });

    metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('AppsListHelper', function () { this.IsMyApp = ko.observable(false); });
}
```

I want to add additional property 'IsMyApp' only for client side usage - in one of my GET method I set this property to 'true':

```
    querySucceded = (data) => {   
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(data.results, (item: m_application.Application) => {
        item.IsMyApp(true);
    });
    return this.apps(data.results);
}
```

Now I try to query local data via breeze manager, using query:

```
private getLocal = (resource) => {
    var query = this.EntityQuery.from(resource).where('IsMyApp', '==', 'true').toType("AppsListHelper");
    return this.breezeManager.executeQueryLocally(query);
}
```

but nothing happens (view is loaded but is blank), after remove line for 'where clause' it returns all data.

Any help will be appreciate :)

My more detailed scenario is as follow: I have 2 views: 'My Apps' and 'All Apps'. Since all entities are the same type 'AppsListHelper', after I received both lists with data from the server they are cached toogether - that caused same data being displayed on two views (its understood for me) when pulled from local cache. So as first solution I wanted to add additional flag 'IsMyApp' only on client side since I really don't need it on a server and distinguish data based on value of this flag for appropriate view.

Comment: I add more detail to post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PKad is correct that a Breeze query ignores unrecognized properties. You could filter the cached-query results as he suggests.

**Unmapped properties** is another option to consider. An unmapped property is "known to Breeze" but not mapped to your database and will not be persisted on the server. It is a client-only extension.

You can define an unmapped property when you define your metadata on the client or you can define it in a custom constructor and register that with the type.

Then you can query it as shown in the DocCode:entityExtensionTests test, ["can query an unmapped property with cache query"](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/DocCode/DocCode/tests/entityExtensionTests.js).

Answer (score 0):

You can only create queries for properties that Breeze knows about.  In your situation you are adding the property onto the constructor but Breeze doesn't really *know* that you are doing it, just allowing you a method to do it. (if that makes any sense)

You are probably just looking to filter the array, so why not do a query for the objects that meet other criteria and then just filter them?  This is probably not valid TypeScript but should show you the right way -

```
var filteredResults = ko.utils.arrayFilter(data.results, function (result) {
    return result.IsMyApp() === true;
});
```